# Media query not responding on window resize, but working in Chrome Dev tools

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to have a "list" (not an `html` list, but just 6 concurrent pictures in a logical fashion) of pictures that go down, but at a certain breakpoint, two move next to each other, and the media query is working in the Chrome dev tools and on Adobe Dreamweaver live preview on the phone, but on browser resize, the media query doesn't respond. Here is the `html`:

```
    <div class="gray-bg">
          <!-- Item 1 -->
            <div class="flexbox-row">
              <div class="sec-heading space-between">
                   <img src="assets/images/header1Web.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" usemap="#plus">
              <map name="plus" id="plus"><area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="1904,371,1898,358,1890,351,1782,423,1917,426,1917,300,1891,321,1875,340,1803,401,1790,415,1782,418" /></map>
              </div>
            <!-- Item 2 -->
              <div class="sec-heading space-between">
                   <img src="assets/images/header2Web.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
              </div>
            </div>
          <!-- Item 3 -->
            <div class="flexbox-row">
              <div class="sec-heading space-between">
             <img src="assets/images/header3Web.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
             </div>
          <!-- Item 4 -->
              <div class="sec-heading space-between">
             <img src="assets/images/header4Web.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
             </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Item 5 -->
            <div class="flexbox-row">
              <div class="sec-heading space-between">
             <img src="assets/images/header5Web.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
             </div>
          <!-- Item 6 -->
              <div class="sec-heading space-between">
             <img src="assets/images/header6Web.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
             </div>
             </div>
    </div><!-- / .gray-bg -->
```

And here is the appropriate `CSS`:

```
.flexbox-row {
    display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1446px) {
.flexbox-row {
    display: flex;
}}
```

Comment: `(min-device-width: 1446px)` is different from `(max-width: 1446px)`, `min-device-width` is checking if you have a screen width of `1446px` while `(max-width: 1446px)` is you have current width of `xxxPX`. No matter how you resize it the screen width is still the same

Comment: @masterpreenz That was it! It was my misunderstanding of media queries!! Thanks!! I'd love to give you the answer!!

Comment: I should have posted it as an answer, there you go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(min-device-width: 1446px)` is different from `(max-width: 1446px)`, `min-device-width` is checking if you have a screen width of 1446px while `(max-width: 1446px)` is if you have current width of 1446px. No matter how you resize it the screen width is still the same.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

to make the flexbox-row react "when the maximum width of the screen is 1446px" the code is:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1446px) {
.flexbox-row {
    display: flex;
}}
```

and not

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1446px) {
.flexbox-row {
    display: flex;
}}
```